# I want to know how to add placeholder to Django Modelforms?

Tags: python, django-models, django-forms, placeholder

I want to know how to add placeholder to Django modelform fields
I have pasted here code from my models.py file and forms.py file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HT3xf.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GO2Do.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve the results that you want .

But the simplest way is to add placeholder to the form field in Django is by following line of code :

```
comment = forms.CharField(max_length=200, placeholder="Text!")
```

And for your case It will be something like :

```
widgets= {
       'title' : forms.TextInput(placeholder="this is my placeholder"),
```

and so on for all fields.

Hope it will resolve the issue. Else let me know.

and please remove attrs keyword argument from forms field because it is causing issue.